# How can I make my dataframe into a numpy array by column rather than by row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider that I have this example dataframe:

```
d = {'Gender': [1,1,0,1,0], 'Employed': [1,0,0,1,1]}
```

I would like this to be an array of this form:

```
[[1 1 0 1 0][1 0 0 1 1]]
```

When I run

```
d[['Gender', 'Employed']].to_numpy()
```

I get an array of the form `[[1 1][1 0][0 0][1 1][0 1]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose the DataFrame, get the underlying numpy array with `values` method and convert to a list with `tolist` method:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(d).T.values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just transpose it.

```
d[['Gender', 'Employed']].values.T
```

Answer (score 0):

This can get your expected output

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender': [1,1,0,1,0], 'Employed': [1,0,0,1,1]})
print([df[column].to_list() for column in df])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Let me know if you expect more from here.